# How do I remove brackets from a printed list?

Tags: python

Context: user inputs employee name, hours worked, and hourly wage. Output is expected to be the entered names, and their total pay. EX: "John   $300". Problem is with what I have it just outputs ('john', 300.0)

```
payroll = 0
employee_list = []
print('Enter Information ( Name, hours worked, hourly rate) seperated by commas')
print('Press Enter to stop Enetering Employee Information')
info = input('Enter Employee Information: ')

while info != '':
    employee_info = info.split(',')
    hours_worked = float(employee_info[1])
    hourly_rate = float(employee_info[2])
    employee_name = employee_info[0].strip()
    employee_info = [employee_name, (hours_worked * hourly_rate)]
    employee_list.append(employee_info)
    payroll += hours_worked * hourly_rate
    info = input('Enter Employee Information: ')
    
print()
print('Total Payroll ${:.2f}'.format(payroll))
print()
print('Employees with Paychecks')
for i in range(len(employee_list)):
    print(employee_list[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, the best option (and most modern approach) is to use a f-string. [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) were introduced with Python 3.6.

```
for i in range(len(employee_list)):
    print(f"{employee_list[i][0]}: ${employee_list[i][1]}")
```

I would like to point out something else but off-topic. Avoid mimicking count-controlled loops if you can use collection-controlled loops. This makes your code more readable:

```py
for employee_info in employee_list:
    print(f"{employee_info[0]}: ${employee_info[1]}")
```

---

```py
from collections import namedtuple

EmployeeInfo = namedtuple("EmployeeInfo", ["name", "total"])

def parse_input(info: str) -> EmployeeInfo:
    name, hours, rate = info.split(",")
    return EmployeeInfo(name.strip(), float(hours)*float(rate))

employee_info_list = []

print("Enter Information (name, hours worked, hourly rate) separated by commas")
print("Press Enter to stop Entering Employee Information")

while True:

    employee_input = input("Enter Employee Information: ")

    if not employee_input:
        break

    employee_info = parse_input(employee_input)

    employee_info_list.append(employee_info)
    
payroll = sum(employee_info.total for employee_info in employee_info_list)

print()
print(f"Total Payroll: ${payroll:.2f}")
print()
print("Employees with Paychecks:")

for employee_info in employee_info_list:
    print(f"{employee_info.name}: ${employee_info.total}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('{} ${}'.format(*employee_list[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting a tuple as an output. You can use an f string to format that variable by calling each item inside curly brackets with a string prefaced by 'f'. For example:

```
tuple = ('text', 100)
print(f'{tuple[0]} ${tuple[1]}')
```

```
output: text $100
```

You can read more in the python documentation on input output, or pep-498:
https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are your friend:

```
payroll = 0
employee_list = []
print('Enter Information ( Name, hours worked, hourly rate) seperated by commas')
print('Press Enter to stop Enterting Employee Information')
info = 'Billy, 1234.3, 42' # input('Enter Employee Information: ')

while info != '':
    process = lambda x, y, z: [x.strip(), float(y), float(z)]
    employee_name, hours_worked, hourly_rate = process(*info.split(','))  
    employee_list.append(f'{employee_name}, ${hours_worked * hourly_rate:.2f}')
    payroll += hours_worked * hourly_rate
    info = '' # input('Enter Employee Information: ')
    
print()
print(f'Total Payroll ${payroll:.2f}')
print()
print('Employees with Paychecks')
for i in range(len(employee_list)):
    print(employee_list[i])
```

Output:

```
Enter Information ( Name, hours worked, hourly rate) seperated by commas
Press Enter to stop Enterting Employee Information

Total Payroll $51840.60

Employees with Paychecks
Billy, $51840.60
```

Answer (score 0):

in your last lines:

```
for i in range(len(employee_list)):
    print(*employee_list[i], sep=",")
```

### 1

***** open a list or tuple as print arguments

### 2

by **sep** argument, set how seperate values from each other in console

Answer (score 0):

Print with expression

```
for i in range(len(employee_list)):
    print(F"{employee_list[i][0]}, {employee_list[i][1]}")
```